# Проблема с Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я создаю 2 функции для прототипа объекта, а в консоль сыпятся ошибки:

> jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: W[g].exec is not a function

Возможно конфликтует что то с `jquery`, подскажите как решить вопрос?

Вот пример функций:

```
Object.prototype.getFirstKey = function () {
        for (var i in this) {
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }



    Object.prototype.getFirstValue = function () {
        for (var i in this) {
            return this[i];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изменять встроенные объекты - очень плохая практика, не используйте её.
Это не `jQuery 2.2.3`:

```js
Object.prototype.getFirstKey = function() {
  for (var i in this) {
    return i;
    break;
  }
}



Object.prototype.getFirstValue = function() {
  for (var i in this) {
    return this[i];
    break;
  }
}

let test = {
  hello: 'world',
  some: 'value'
};

console.info(test.getFirstKey(), ' | ', test.getFirstValue());
console.info('Всё работает без ошибок, версия jQuery: %s', $().jquery);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**UPDATE:**

```js
let arr = JSON.parse`[ { "hash1": { "color": "blue", "size": "1", "count": 1 } }, { "hash2": { "color": "red", "size": "22", "count": 22 }},{ "hash3": { "color": "red", "size": "22", "count": 22 }}]`;

// Перебираем объекты объектов
arr.forEach(e => {
  // Перебираем сами объекты
  Object.keys(e).forEach(hash => {
    console.info(hash, e[hash]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Ну в моём случае не знаю другого варианта как не изменить встроенный обьект просто. Хотелось бы уточнить фразу "Это не jQuery 2.2.3:" вы имеете в виду что у меня не 2.2.3 жквери и поэтому ошибка?

Comment: Я имею ввиду что на версии 2.2.3 ошибки нет. Вы вряд ли изменяли сообщение о ошибке (а если да, то это глупо, помочь не можем), так что Ваша проблема не в этом. Скажите причины изменения глобальных объектов, просто я только одну дельную причину знаю и Вы не её сделали.

Comment: причина  в необходимом разборе немного не простой структуры данных, возможно есть и проще способ, но мне пришёл на ум этот =)  : var myBasketKey = [

  {
    "hash1": {
      "color": "blue",
      "size": "1",
      "count": 1
    }
  }, {
    "hash2": {
      "color": "red",
      "size": "22",
      "count": 22
    }
  },{
  ...
  }
] - и это всё помещаю в локал сторадж

Comment: @user3319778, это решается любым циклом и уж точно не изменением прототипа `Object`.

Comment: @user3319778, обновил пример, перебор отлично работает. Правда структура слегка плохо построена - зачем в массив оборачивать, если объект отлично справляется и глубина меньше?

Comment: Спасибо.Так как добавляя данные в обьект в хаотичном порядке, он автоматически сортирует последовательно по ключу все элементы - по численному возрастанию или буквенному, к примеру если я в обьект положу ключ 1, потом ключ 3 и ключ 2, то хранится они будут там не в этом порядке а последовательном - 1,2,3  исходя из этого я обернул всё в массив.